# How to share toolbar between activity and fragment?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-navigation

My application uses only one `Activity` globally, and all the navigation components are in this `Activity`.

I have such a requirement that after selecting an item in `ListFragment`, `Toolbar` should enter selected mode. as follows:

[image]

[image]

**How to achieve this mode switch?**

Comment: Checkout the documentation for `Activity.startActionMode(actionModeCallback)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ActionMode`, the guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

If you use `startActionMode` to use `ActionMode` in the `Fragment`, and close it in `Activity`, you can override `onActionModeStarted` function in `Activity` and get `ActionMode`.

Mofity `ActionMode` style: [How to specify dark action mode with my theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118160/how-to-specify-dark-action-mode-with-my-theme)

Thank you for @DarShan